# How to use active and passive modes of AWS FTP?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ftp

I am using an AWS ubuntu instance as FTP server and done the required configurations by following below link.

http://sdykman.com/content/installing-vsftpd-ubuntu-1404-amazon-ec2-instance

In my java application i am using Apache FTPClient to connect the FTP server. When i am testing the file download from FTP server from local machine with windows OS it is working fine without **ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();**

So my code is like below for Windows OS.

```
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("\Sample.xls");
```

But the same application when i ported to another AWS instance and trying to download the file, it is not working. I must have to specify **ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();** here. Now only it is working.

```
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("\Sample.xls");
```

I am confused in understanding the exact difference between these two scenarios. Can some one please explain me what the problem is and how to modify the code to work in both scenarios.

Comment: Use `enterLocalPassiveMode` in both scenarios. See my article on [FTP passive and active modes](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) to understand. Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here anyway.

Comment: Thanks Martin. In both cases enterLocalPassiveMode is working. Thanks for the article.